# How to get the "Return" key from the Android TouchScreenKeyboard (Unity, C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an `InputField` component that once I press my physical keyboard key **Return** the text in the `InputField` is saved. I want the same thing to happen when pressing my Android TouchScreenKeyboard "OK" or "Done" (I also tested with `keyCode.Enter` and that does not work). Do you know a specific KeyCode for it? Or maybe another way to achieve this?

This is the code that works with my physical keyboard:

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return) || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.KeypadEnter))
{
   doThis(); //Saving the input's text to a variable
}
```

I want the same result when pressing "OK" or "Done" in my Android's TouchKeyboard. When pressing the mentioned choices, the TouchKeyboard gets hidden but the data in the `InputField` doesn't submit. I have created an on-screen button that calls the function `doThis()` as a workaround, but I want to avoid this.

Comment: Are you using the uGUI input field?

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to InputField's onEndEdit event, its quite reliable at firing whenever the user is done entering text, weather its pressing enter or just loosing focus of that window, it gets fired when the user is done typing, I believe it should solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

this works fine for me (PC/Mobile), try it out

```
    this.yourInput.onSubmit.AddListener(delegate {
    if (this.yourInput.text.Length > 0)
        //do something when enter or done (mobile)
});
```

Comment: This will also execute if the user unfocuses from the soft keyboard without pressing 'done'  button (ie taps on the top part of screen)

Adding a `if (Utils.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))` under the length > 0 condition doesn't help since the "done" key doesn't seen to be KeyCode.Return